# Most efficient/pythonic way to prepend string if variable is true

Tags: python

I have code similar to the following in several places:

```
if myvar:
    thestr = "Extra text"
else:
    thestr = "text"
```

I've thought about shortening the code by changing it to something like this:

```
thestr = "%stext" % "Extra " if myvar else ""
```

Since it's doing an if/else either way, I suspect that the second method is slower since it also has to do the string concatenation. However, the code is shorter which is nice. And changes to "text" only need to be changed once.

What is the best way to do this? Any other recommended ways are fine too.

Comment: Are you trying to make a noun plural if a number is not 1?  If so, that's a much more specific problem, and would benefit from writing a single `pluralize()` function.

Comment: "Best" is kind of subjective. Your original text is certainly clearest. You can shorten it into two lines by removing the line break after each `:`.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific about what I meant by best. I am looking to be python and ensure I follow recommended python guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't see much of a noticeable speed difference here (sorted in ascending order of time taken) :

```
 In [89]: %timeit "%stext" % "Extra " if np.random.randint(-5,5)>0  else ""
1000000 loops, best of 3: 738 ns per loop

In [91]: paste
def test():
        myvar = np.random.randint(-5, 5)
        if myvar > 0:
            thestr = "Extra text"
        else:
            thestr = "text"

%timeit test()

## -- End pasted text --
1000000 loops, best of 3: 853 ns per loop


In [90]: %timeit "%stext" % ("Extra " if np.random.randint(-5,5)>0 else "")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 871 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the ternary is shortest in code. And concatenation is fast so that's not a concern. Readability and errors *are*, and you did make a mistake with it.

You need to be more explicit about what the if case is. In your example, a False boolean would give "" instead of text. You want to do this:

```
thestr = "%stext" % ("Extra " if myvar else "")
```

That way you're telling "%stext" to format itself with the ternary expression contained in the brackets.

In what I presume this case is, it seems unlikely that a ternary is worth it given the potential for reading them wrong and tiny errors. You can easily add a couple lines without it taking up a bunch of code.

The better use I've found for them is when making a dictionary, I might need some parameters to be based on conditions and it's easier if I can declare them all in one go rather than having a series of if blocks after making the dictionary.

```
food = { 
         "peanuts":   "delicious",
         "chocolate": "tasty",
         "banana":    "tasty" if peeled else "eugh",
         "apple":     "ok",
         "python":    "ew" if snake else "???",
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see what mistake I made. If you copy and paste what I wrote it works exactly as I want it for both myvar being True or False

Comment: Oh, weird. When I ran your code I got just a blank string, might be a difference with my version of Python? (2.7) It's recommended to use brackets anyway if the evaluation hierarchy is ambiguous, as it's clearer to humans reading it.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Which is why the `Python` tag should be burned. `Python2` is very different from `Python3`.

Comment: @mhost: On what Python version (and perhaps interpreter)? (Also, could you recheck it?) I tried it on Python 2.5-3.4 and got an empty string on all of them.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I tried it again and it was wrong (I glanced over it too quickly when I tried it earlier). You were right that the brackets are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the if/else on multiple lines is how I'd generally code it. But I place high value on clarity/obviousness, and it's the clearest/most obvious solution possible, imo. Also, I generally just use the `+` operator for string concatenation these days, and prefer that over your printf-style `%` substitution. As a result, I'd do this as:

```
if myvar:
    theStr = 'Extra ' + 'text'
else:
    theStr = 'text'
```

or similar. If you want, you can get rid of the else condition pretty easily:

```
theStr = 'text'
if myvar:
    theStr = 'Extra ' + theStr
```

Comment: I think `text` in your examples needs to be `"text"`

Comment: yep, I think you're right. Fixing it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is largely an opinion-based question, but one other alternative presents itself if `myvar` is boolean

```
text = ["text","Extra text"]
thestr = text[myvar]
```

this avoids the "if...else" of either of your approaches, but is somewhat obfuscated.

If `myvar` is *not* boolean, you can coerce it with

```
text = ["text","Extra text"]
thestr = text[bool(myvar)]
```

or, as Mark said

```
text = ["text","Extra text"][bool(myvar)]
```

Otherwise, the first approach has the value of clarity

Comment: You can even shorten that: `["text","Extra text"][myvar]`. That just makes it even *more* head-scratching though.

Comment: Yep, just playing around. But sometimes this type if trick as actually "useful" ... very rarely though